# I need to compare standered deviation for 3 weeks in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below source table :

```
date        Growthrate
----------  ----------
2015-04-05, 0.4
2015-04-12, 0.3
2015-04-19, 0.2
2015-04-26, 0.7
2015-05-03, 0.8
2015-05-10, 0.9
2015-05-17, 0.8
2015-05-24, 0.2
2015-05-31, 0.6
```

destination table should be:

```
WeekNumber, result
1, 
2, 
3, good
4, poor
```

the result value is good if the growthrate is 2 stdev away comparing to last 3 weeks

Comment: How do you count a week? Your question is unclear..

Comment: Weeknumber is the week derived from the date. All dates are weekending dates

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, because of the windowed standard deviation calculation.  I assume that once you have that, the `case` expression is trivial.

You want to be able to do:

```
select t.*,
       (select std(t2.growthrate)
        from (select t2.*
              from t t2
              where t2.weeknumber <= t.weeknumber and t2.weeknumber >= t.weeknumber - 2
              order by t2.weeknumber desc
              limit 3
             )
       ) as std
from t;
```

MySQL doesn't let you do that.  So, you are stuck with a `join`:

```
select t.weeknumber, t.growthrate,
       std(t2.growthrate) as std,
       avg(t2.growthrate) as avg
from t join
     t t2
     where t2.weeknumber <= t.weeknumber and
           t2.weeknumber >= t.weeknumber - 2
group by t.weeknumber, t.growthrate;
```

Having said all that, I think it is a mistake to be using the standard deviation based on three points.

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . The OP can do the same thing with the `date` column.  I find the question unclear as to what exactly is in the data.  The logic what to do is the same, except for tweaks to the date arithmetic.